# asp.net razor iis rewrite all requests to a file

Tags: asp.net, razor, url-rewriting, iis-8

This has probably been asked before but I haven't so far hit on the correct search terms.

I'm using IIS8
I have a file called Index.cshtml which contains my page logic - retrieving page content from database.

So, a URL of www.mysite.com/Index/mypage works correctly usng mypage' as a parameter.
However, I'm trying to create a rewrite rule in web.config so that I can have the URLs as www.mysite.com/mypage etc.

Also, I want the root www.mysite.com/ to rewrite to www.mysite.com/Index/home

I've tried many things, so far not working - either I send it into a loop of adding many /Index/Index/index... or, just page not found.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer was to use routing instead, reference http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/187/more-flexible-routing-for-asp-net-web-pages

adding the following into my _AppStart.cshtml

RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("sitemap.xml");
RouteTable.Routes.MapWebPageRoute("{cat}/{article}/{tag}/{page}",     "~/Index.cshtml", new { cat = "", article = "", tag = "", page = "" });